# How to add search and checkbox icon with their functions in android action bar?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-menu

I want to add a searchview and checkbox into action bar menu. And this checkbox will be visible if searchview is opened. And in it's opposite case it will be hidden. How I can do this?
I do something below . But it doesnt work correctly. I want hide checkbox (In my notes) when searchview is closed.
**menu.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_search"
            android:title="Arama"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"

            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">

        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search_in_my_notes_checkbox"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/search_in_my_notes"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:visible="false"

            />
    </menu>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.search_button){
            MenuItem searchInMyNotesCheckbox = (MenuItem)menu.findItem(R.id.search_in_my_notes_checkbox);
            searchInMyNotesCheckbox.setVisible(true);
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution.  I will use two checkbox image with checked and unchecked. And I will override onCreateOptionsMenu like this :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem search = (MenuItem)menu.findItem(R.id.search_button2);
    final MenuItem searchInMyNotesCheckbox = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.search_in_my_notes_checkbox);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(search,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // Return true to allow the action view to expand

                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    MenuItem searchInMyNotesCheckbox = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.search_in_my_notes_checkbox);
                    searchInMyNotesCheckbox.setVisible(false);
                    return true;
                }
            });

    searchInMyNotesCheckbox.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            if(item.getIcon() == R.drawable.checked_checkbox){
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.unchecked_checkbox);
            }
            else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.checked_checkbox);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```